# reactjs can't show data in my jsx using map method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux

Hi I am using redux but can't show data in my jsx using map method. getting this error  `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')` see also screenshot2 where I can see my data is receiving from api. If my data is receiving then why getting this error?

```
const PostAds = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [category,setCategory] = useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchcategory = async ()=>{
    const data = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/ads_category/")
    const r = dispatch(ads_category(data)) 
    setCategory(r)
    } 
    fetchcategory()

  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
   
     console.log("redux_data",category)
  }, [category]);

  
    return (
      <>
       {category.payload.data.map((data)=>{
        return(data.main_category)
       })}
     </>
     
  )
}

export default PostAds
```

**seceenshot2**

[image]

**screnshot1**
[image]

Comment: `category` is an array.  It would never have a property called `payload`.  What are you expecting that to be and why?

Comment: I want to show my all category and sub category name in my jsx

Comment: also tried this ` {category.data.map((data)=>(
        <>
        <li>{data.main_category}</li>
        </>
       ))}` but still now same problems

Answer (score 1):

Be consistent with your types.

According to the data in the screen shot, you expect `category` to be an object with a property called `payload`.  But you're initially setting `category` to an empty array:

```
const [category,setCategory] = useState([])
```

So should it be an object or an array?  An array will never have a property called `payload`.

First, don't set it to an array if you don't want it to be an array.  If you give it no initial value at all, it will be `undefined`:

```
const [category,setCategory] = useState()
```

Then in the JSX, use optional chaining when referencing it so that if it's `undefined` it just outputs nothing:

```
<>
  {category?.payload.data.map((data)=>{
    return(data.main_category)
  })}
</>
```

If there are cases where the `payload` property might not be defined, or any other property, you could use the same approach.

Comment: getting empty data after using your code. No data showing

Comment: @boyenec: On the first render, or also on subsequent renders?  What data do you observably have when debugging?  Nobody here knows what data you're using, that's something *you* need to be aware of in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `category` is a simple state variable in this case, and doesn't have to do anything with redux. You must use the state stored in redux, not the component itself. For that matter, `dispatch(ads_category(data))` should suffice.

Secondly, your `useEffect` is called AFTER the first render, which means you are only fetching data into `category` after the component has already tried to render once. So `category.payload.data.map` will obviously error out since `category` doesn't have the value you want it to have.

Since this is a basic problem, try to understand why you're getting this error so it doesn't repeat in the future.

For an immediate solution, try going with this:

```js
{category?.payload?.data?.map((data)=>{
    return(data.main_category)
})}
```